# Prisma: find where field is not set

Tags: prisma

Say I have a schema like so:

```js
model Person {
  id      String   @id @default(cuid())
  name    String
  email   String?
}
```

How could I *find all persons named "foo" with no email*? Basically, `findMany` or `update` based on `name IS "foo"` AND `email IS NOT SET`? I find the doc on the subject very confusing.

Could it be:

```js
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    email: undefined,
  }
})
```

or:

```js
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    email: null,
  }
})
```

or:

```js
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    email: { is: null },
  }
})
```

or ... ???

---

Does it change anything if it's an optional relation?

```js
model Person {
  id      String   @id @default(cuid())
  name    String
  pet     Pet?     @relation
}
model Pet {
  id      String   @id @default(cuid())
  name    String
  ownerId String?
  owner   Person?  @relation(fields: [ownerId], references: [id])
}
```

How can I *find all persons named "foo" with no pet*? Is it different from *finding all pets named "foo" with no owner"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How could I find all persons named "foo" with no email?*

**Correct answer** is:

```js
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    email: null,
  }
})
```

---

```ls
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    email: undefined,
  }
})
```

Using `undefined` will equivalent to :

```js
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
  }
})
```

So this basically find all person with name `foo` include who have email and do not have email, that's **wrong**.

---

```js
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    email: { is: null },
  }
})
```

Using `is` is only for relation query, so it's probably won't work.

---

*How can I find all persons named "foo" with no pet?*

```js
prisma.person.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    pet: { none: {} },
  }
})
```

---

*Is it different from finding all pets named "foo" with no owner"?*

I think it's the same

```js
prisma.pet.findMany({
  where: {
    name: "foo",
    owner: { none: {} },
  }
})
```